# Create compact/human-friendly floats using unicode vulgar fractions

Tags: python, unicode, floating-point

Are there any modules (preferably in the standard library), that can turn a float number into something the is more human friendly?  Maybe it's not more human friendly, but at least more compact.

eg. 4.625 would become "4⅝"

(Bonus brownie points for recognizing pi to a reasonable precision)

This code outline was the best I could come up with:

```
import unicodedata

def simplify_float(number):
    vf = "VULGAR FRACTION "
    vulgars = {0.125 : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "ONE EIGHTH"),
               0.2   : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "ONE FIFTH"),
               0.25  : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "ONE QUARTER"),
               0.375 : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "THREE EIGHTHS"),
               0.4   : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "TWO FIFTHS"),
               0.5   : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "ONE HALF"),
               0.6   : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "THREE FIFTHS"),
               0.625 : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "FIVE EIGHTHS"),
               0.75  : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "THREE QUARTERS"),
               0.8   : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "FOUR FIFTHS"),
               0.875 : unicodedata.lookup(vf + "SEVEN EIGHTHS")}

    decimal = int(number)
    if number == decimal:
        return unicode(decimal)

    vulgar = vulgars.get(number - decimal)
    if vulgar:
        if decimal == 0:
            return vulgar
        return "%d%s" % (decimal, vulgar)
    return "%.1f" % number
```

Going the other direction is pretty easy using the unicodedata module, but I couldn't find a good way to author these strings in the first place.

Comment: Sympy can help identify multiples, fractions & powers of pi, e, etc...

Comment: Thats a pretty neat module. It looks like it can recognize those things but doesn't necessarily utilize the unicode characters for fractions. I'm mostly looking for some common unicode fractions to make a more compact but still readable ui

Comment: Sympy can use LaTex; I don't know about unicode.

Comment: The fractions with powers of 2 in the denominator will be exact, but others (like 1/3) might give you trouble when you use them as the key for a dict because of round-off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [only twenty of these fraction forms in Unicode](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Decomposition_Type=Fraction:]). It is unlikely that there will ever be more (as they only exist for backwards compatibility with other character sets), so hardcoding them is probably robust enough.

The *general* way of encoding fractions is to use `⁄` U+2044 FRACTION SLASH. Font shaping/layout engines are allowed to render numbers with a fraction slash (e.g., 1⁄2) with as a slanted or stacked fraction (e.g., ½)—however, I have not encountered any that do (and even the plain rendering is unfortunately quite ugly).

```
import math
import fractions

VULGAR_FRACTIONS = {(5, 8) : '\u215D', ...}

def compact_float(number):
    parts = math.modf(number)
    fraction = fractions.Fraction(parts[0])
    simple = (fraction.numerator, fraction.denominator)
    form = VULGAR_FRACTIONS.get(simple)
    return '%i%s' % (parts[1], form) if form else str(number)
```

It's not clear what the best way is to handle precision (e.g., `1/3`) as it will depend on the format your numbers exist in and how much error is acceptable.

Comment: Can you combine the fraction slash with superscript/subscript numbers?

Comment: No, it's not intended to work with them. Only "decimal numbers" are supported (super/subscript numbers are classified as "other numbers" and are generally not recommended for use).

Comment: I would use 1/3 only if number is the nearest float to the fraction (intPart*3+1)/3. Eventually this could be downgraded when number matches float(intPart + float(1/3)), but this double rounding does not sound very satisfying...